# Extract Zipcode, city, state from defaultAddress Netsuite

Tags: c#, netsuite

I'm newbie with Netsuite Web service.

I'm trying to get address, city, state and zipcode from vendor.

Base on document, i can see vendor have  attribute addressbookList (type VendorAddressbookList).

But when i use this code :

```
Record[] records = response.recordList;

        Vendor vendor;
        for (int i = 0, j = (response.pageIndex - 1) * _pageSize; i < records.Length; i++, j++)
        {
            vendor = (Vendor)records[i];
            _out.info(
                "\n  Record[" + j + "]: " +
                "\n    internalId=" + vendor.internalId +
                "\n    entityId=" + vendor.entityId +
                (vendor.phone == null ? "" : ("\n    Phone=" + vendor.phone)) +
                (vendor.email == null ? "" : ("\n    email=" + vendor.email)) +
                (vendor.defaultAddress == null ? "" : ("\n    address=" + vendor.defaultAddress)));                
        }
```

With debug tool, the value of vendor.addressbookList is null, so that i cannot get zipcode, state, city and address from that.

Only vendor.defaultAddress has value (example : Maxson Waste Management
239 S Post Ave San Jose CA 95118
US) (with "br" tag for new line)

I can workaround by split this string but it seem not a regular way .

Please hint me!
Any help is appreciate !
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer, i need to use RecordRef for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the OA's solution, I ran into this problem today as well, and the fact that oa has pointed for `RecordRef` is not very clear.

It turned out that type `RecordRef`s are returned through the `get` or `getList` operation, if you are using search, then you won't have `RecordRef` returned thus no access to `addressbookList`.